# JavaScript cannot find JSON data from PHP json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

The idea here is to automatically load (or load at all) my index page with some products out of a MySQL database table.

Firstly, my PHP.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once 'classloader.php';
$db = new Database();

$items = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM products');

foreach($items as $eachItem){
    $itemsJSON = new Item($eachItem->product_name, $eachItem->product_quantity, $eachItem->product_cost);
    echo json_encode($itemsJSON);
}
```

This seems to be working great, and gives me two properly encoded JSON objects of my Item class.

```
{"name":"Slippers","quantity":"3","cost":"4.00"}
{"name":"Gloves","quantity":"5","cost":"9.00"}
```

My JavaScript looks like this(and many other similar variations)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post( "productloader.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#result" ).html( data );
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why it is not working. I did not want to use `$.getJSON()` because there is no query string to work with, so I'd assume I would need `$.post()`.

It seems like this is a pretty common issue, but I've not found a solution yet. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console? Are there any errors?

Comment: Once the AJAX request receives the first successful result from the `echo json_encode($itemsJSON);`, it stops listening for a response and all subsequent iterations of your `foreach` loop will be ignored (in the JavaScript). You'll need to add each `Item` to an array and then return the full array `json_encode()`ed.

Comment: I don't think  you should have this inside the loop:  `json_encode($itemsJSON)` - it should be outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `json_encode()` each item separately. The data you're sending to the browser is not valid JSON, just many little chunks of valid JSON one after the other. Build an array inside your loop and then encode the whole thing. See also http://jsonlint.com/

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once 'classloader.php';
$db = new Database();

$items = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM products');

foreach($items as $eachItem){    
    $itemsJSON[] = new Item($eachItem->product_name, $eachItem->product_quantity, $eachItem->product_cost);
}

echo json_encode($itemsJSON);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your method of `AJAX`, you're outputting multiple `JSON` strings while the js side is expecting 1 string `(data)`. Try removing your for loop to just:

```
echo json_encode($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating JSON for each row, so you are getting separate JSON objects for each row in front end.

You should put all row in to and array and create the JSON object outside the loop, and echo the encoded JSON string.

```
<?php
    $allitem = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM products');
    $itemArr=array();
    foreach($allitem as $item){    
        array_push( $itemArr ,  new Item($item->product_name, $item->product_quantity, $item->product_cost) );
    }

    echo json_encode($itemArr);
?>
```

or

```
    $allitem = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM products');
    echo json_encode($allitem );
```